# Passing variables into middleware Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am using wildcard subdomains and want to pass the `$element` variable into the middleware whitelabel so I can check the subdomain and respond accordingly.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{element}.website.co', 'middleware' => 'whitelabel'], function() {

    Route::get('/', 'AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('/', 'AuthController@postLogin');

});
```

How would I use the value of element within the middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, (unless you already have done) you'll need to add the following to your:

```
Route::pattern('element', '[a-z0-9.]+');
```

You can add it to the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider`.

Then to access it in your middleware you would have something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $domain = $request->route('element');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Hope this helps!